# Error messages combining group_by and as.numeric in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a `dataset`

```
Gene Sample  Ctmean

Chr1 0.0032 38.30534

Chr1  0.016 38.05460

Chr2 0.0032 34.96991
```

and so on, wherein the sample names "Sample" were initially defined as characters (some are names, some numbers). I have filtered for just the ones which are numbers so I can use these for one analysis, with the named ones for later separate analysis, but when trying to group them by another column for this analysis I am running into the error message

> Error in function_list[k] : 
>    (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

after using

```
group_by(forstandardcurve,Gene) %>% as.numeric(forstandardcurve$Sample)
```

Conversely if I use

```
as.numeric(forstandardcurve$Sample) %>% group_by(forstandardcurve,Gene)
```

I get

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
>    no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class >"c('double', 'numeric')"

although the "`Gene`" column should still be '`character`' too. 
Each command looks like it is working as I expect when run by itself. I am very new to R so sorry if this is a basic error I have made - how do I fix this so I can use the numbers in "`Sample`" to plug into equations, with separate equations for each group in the "`Gene`" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert `class` in your example as a stand-alone command, but it makes more sense to convert `class` in the context of another R verb. For instance, let's say you want to calculate the mean of `Sample` grouped by `Gene`.

Starting with your data, where `Sample` is a character:

```
df <- data.frame( Gene = c("Chr1","Chr1","Chr2"),
              Sample = c("0.0032","0.016","0.0032"),
              Ctmean = c(38.3, 38.0, 34.9))
```

You can do:

```
df %>%
   group_by(Gene) %>%
   summarise( Sample = mean( as.numeric(as.character(Sample)) ) )
```

Note that I had to change from `factor` to `character` first, before cnverting to `numeric`. This gives:

```
1   Chr1 0.0096
2   Chr2 0.0032
```

Comment: This has worked fine the first time I've used it in this script (prior to the above I had `qpcrmeans <- select(qpcr,Ct,Sample,Gene) %>% group_by(Gene,Sample) %>% summarise(Ctmean = mean(Ct))
forstandardcurve <- filter(qpcrmeans,grepl("4|0.8|0.016|0.0032",Sample)) %>% filter(!is.na(Ctmean))` ). But is not subsequently working, is this perhaps because it is already grouped? I can see now using str() that the file upon which this worked is a data.frame whereas the one which is not working says grouped_df.

Comment: Most likely...you can ungroup by chaining `%>% ungroup()` to the rest

Comment: Perfect, upvoting for the comment as well.